# How can I show the key and value of an object in Google Tagmanager?

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

I have an object stored in my LocalStorage with keys and values. I want to retrieve that object and put both the key and value in some HTML. I used this code and works fine in my console:

```
const object1 = {
  a: 'somestring',
  b: 42
};
for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(object1)) {
  
  console.log(`${key}: ${value}`);
}
```

Now I get multiple errors that the language feature is only supported for ECMASCRIPT_2015 mode or better. How can I fix this so that I can show the keys and corresponding value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It actually is telling you to not use ES6 features. Yes, unfortunately, Google doesn't see its GTM product as a very important to their business, so they limit the resources spent on it severely.

As a result, GTM doesn't support ES6, aka Ecma Script 2015. Yep, no support for new JS features like const, for..of, etc. You have to rewrite your code, like so:

```js
function(){
  var object1 = {
    a: 'somestring',
    b: 42
  };
  Object.keys(object1).forEach(function(key){
    console.log(key, object1[key]);
  })
  return "";
}
```

I wrapped it in a function to be used in a GTM var. If you meant it to be a CHTML tag (which I advice against), feel free to get rid of the wrapping function and return.